# AR(p) model worse than no-change model for currency exchange rate

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive, finance, mse

I am using $AR(p)$ model to make one-step foreast for M1 returns EURUSD. Does not matter if I use $p=2$ or $p=100$. Always simple forecast that $\hat r_{t+1} = 0$ gives lower Mean Squared Error than my AR model.
Where is the problem? Learning window size (I checked 500, 5000, 10000) or just this that M1 data has lot of candles with $r_t == 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a constant model 
$$
r_t=0+\varepsilon_t
$$
with $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t|I_{t-1})=0$ (where $I_t$ is the information available at time $t-1$) is a better approximation to the data generating process than an AR($p$) model, regardless of $p$. Currency exchange rates are notoriously hard to predict, thus it is unsurprising for you to find that an AR($p$) model cannot predict them.

Comment: I would like to add, that in case of currency exchange rates it might be more appropriate to model the volatility than the mean, maybe by employing a GARCH model.

Comment: @MichaelL., nice insight, although tangential to the question. If we look from a practitioner's perspective, we would not change our goal just because another goal is easier to reach. Paraphrasing Tukey, a poor (but correct) answer to the right question is better than a good answer to the wrong question. In academia, people can choose to study the conditional variance if they see they cannot work with the conditional mean (i.e. they can choose the question). Meanwhile, in business you do not change the question so easily...

Comment: @RichardHardy So I cannot expect that similar to AR models like ARMA will give me better MSE than no-change model?

Comment: @MateuszZaborski, I would not expect that if I were you. You could always overfit in sample, but out of sample the no-change model should beat ARMA most of the time.